# The item in collection is not getting deleted automatically after using "expires" in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I want to delete a particular item from the mongo collection after a given time. I tried expireAfterSeconds using mongoose schema, expires in index of schema and different methods. Even after 60 seconds also when
I refresh my mongo database the item in collection is present and after 10 mins also it is there and not getting delted automatically

I tried in two different ways

timeCreated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: 20
  },

admin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    index : {expires: '10s'}
  },

Comment: Can you post the full schema code to show how you're using the schema constructor?

Comment: var user = new mongoose.Schema{ user_deleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  token: {
    type: [String],
    index : {expires: '10s'}
  }}

Comment: This problem seems more complex than I expected, since you are trying to expire an item and not a whole collection. I think this article will help: https://dojotipsntricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/custom-expiry-times-for-mongoose-documents-in-node-js/

Comment: I tried this also but of no use

Comment: I looked at this article: https://medium.com/@Baresse/auto-expire-documents-with-mongodb-772fee84cc23 which describes the underlying method using the MongoDB driver. It looks like an option without using Mongoose is to use the native driver to create an expiry index explicitly.

Comment: for doing this I tried                                                                           db.users.createIndex( { "token":1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 } ) in linux terminal but after sometime I used                                                 
db.users.find() to get all the items of collection after 10 mins the also in terminal it is showing there.
,